# IBM COS: Not able to write to it from Apache Spark running locally

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, ibm-cloud, object-storage

I'm trying to write to IBM Cloud Object Storage (COS) from Spark running locally but getting NoClassDefFoundError. I'm following this as refrence link:

https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/analyze-data-faster-using-spark-and-ibm-cloud-object-storage-s3-vs-swift-api/

I have created core-site.xml with my ibmcos credentials.

```
Starting spark-shell with stocator package



spark-shell --packages com.ibm.stocator:stocator:1.0.28
val data = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
val distData = sc.parallelize(data)
distData.saveAsTextFile("cos://UNIQUE_BUCKET_NAME.myCos/one1.txt")
```

> Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/amazonaws/AmazonServiceException   at
>   com.ibm.stocator.fs.ObjectStoreVisitor.getStoreClient(ObjectStoreVisitor.java:116)
>   at
>   com.ibm.stocator.fs.ObjectStoreFileSystem.initialize(ObjectStoreFileSystem.java:105)

Comment: Did you install the required packages and use the `--jars` option to point to the downloaded jar?

Comment: I ran with (spark-shell --packages com.ibm.stocator:stocator:1.0.28) this to install packages,  and i think once we run with --package option jar will be automatically available

Comment: I tried with below as well Downloaded jar files manually from https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.ibm.stocator  Then ran spark-shell --jars file:///C:/Users/RohitKumar/Desktop/MyProjects/stocator/stocator-1.0.33.jar ,But still getting same error pls help

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that Stocator jar is not on the class path of Spark. This is not Stocator related, more general question how to introduce additional jars to Spark.  Spark packages suppose to work and this is the preferable way to use it.  It's not a good idea to download jar manually. Did you follow "usage with Apache Spark" from the readme of Stocator project?